# I am unable to have the date appear if i placed it in the <head> portion of code. But it will appear when placed after the <body>

Tags: html

I am new to HTML and currently trying to have my code display the time in the Current Date text box. However, when the code is placed in the `<head>` section, the time and date won't show. It will only show when the code is placed after the `<body>` section. Any reason for it to be this way?

```js
           function getDate() {
            var todaydate = new Date(); 
            var day = todaydate.getDate();
            var month = todaydate.getMonth() + 1;
            var year = todaydate.getFullYear();
            var hours = todaydate.getHours();
            var minutes = todaydate.getMinutes();
            var seconds = todaydate.getSeconds();
            var datestring = (day + "/" + month + "/" + year + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
            document.getElementById("Date").value = datestring;
        }
        getDate()
        setInterval(getDate, 1000);
```

Comment: Can you please add your HTML

Answer (score 0):

Well it will run only after the `id="Date"` is created as JavaScript will through error , if you use it before it created you will see a error as there no element with such name.

> Put your `script` before and after your `id="Date"` and see the difference.

So it is always recommended to put at the bottom of the `html` and near `</body>` tag

See here in below snippet (**when `script` placed after `id="Date"`**) :

```html
<div id="Date"></div>

<script>
  function getDate() {
    var todaydate = new Date();
    var day = todaydate.getDate();
    var month = todaydate.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = todaydate.getFullYear();
    var hours = todaydate.getHours();
    var minutes = todaydate.getMinutes();
    var seconds = todaydate.getSeconds();
    var datestring = (day + "/" + month + "/" + year + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
    document.getElementById("Date").innerHTML = datestring;
  }
  getDate()
  setInterval(getDate, 1000);
</script>
```

Also see in below snippet (**when `script` placed before `id="Date"`**) :

```html
<script>
  function getDate() {
    var todaydate = new Date();
    var day = todaydate.getDate();
    var month = todaydate.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = todaydate.getFullYear();
    var hours = todaydate.getHours();
    var minutes = todaydate.getMinutes();
    var seconds = todaydate.getSeconds();
    var datestring = (day + "/" + month + "/" + year + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
    document.getElementById("Date").innerHTML = datestring;
  }
  getDate()
  setInterval(getDate, 1000);
</script>

<div id="Date"></div>
```

It will throw an error as till now no `id="Date"` defined